# How to control events in a loop of Popup in Kivy/Python to introduce information

Tags: python-3.x, event-handling, popup, kivy

I have an APP in Python 3.4 Kivy 1.10 with the following problem. I want to control events in a Loop 'for' that display Popup in each turn. I try to open the first popup of the loop select a file in filechooser and,  after that, close the popup and open the next one in order to fill a list with the adress of all files. 
The problem is that I open all the popup of the loop and I don't achieve the sequence I want (open popup 1 ->introduce file 1 -> close popup 1 ---> open popup 2 ->introduce file 2 -> close popup 2 ->... -> open popup n ->introduce file n -> close popup n)

I have write a short code of my problem(open the six popup of the loop at the same time)

Any help will be appreciate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Principal>:
    orientation:'vertical'

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.25,0.25,0.25
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'start'
        on_release: root.start()

<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: 0.9,0.9
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Choose File"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        FileChooserListView:
        Button:
            size_hint_y: .2
            text: 'Close'
            on_press: root.dismiss()

''')

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass

class Principal(BoxLayout):

    def start(self):
        for i in range(6):      
            the_popup =CustomPopup()
            the_popup.open()    

class TestApp(App):
    title = 'Test Popup filler filechooser'
    def build(self):
        return Principal()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless FileChooser has it in-built, I don't see you adding the file path to a list anywhere in your code?

You should check out the kivy documentation on it, especially the save/load properties: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html

Comment: That part of the code is not included because it is not important for the problem that I have. That part works well. You do not tell me anything about the event control of the loop popup.